# C# - Add Datagridview Column to a Listbox with a for loop

Tags: c#, datagridview, listbox

I need to add a single column from a 'datagridview' access database to a 'listbox' using a for loop. What I have so far is returning no errors but is not retrieving any data.

```
private void frmProject6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'enrollmentsDataSet.Enrollments' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.enrollmentsTableAdapter.Fill(this.enrollmentsDataSet.Enrollments);

    }

    private void lstUniqueInstructor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lstUniqueInstructor.Items.Clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < this.dgvEnrollments.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            this.lstUniqueInstructor.Items.Add(this.dgvEnrollments.Columns[4].HeaderText);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd loop through the DataTable instead of the DataGridView.

Something like:

```
for (int i=0; i< datatable.Rows.Count; i++){
    this.lstUniqueInstructor.Items.Add(datatable.Rows[i][4].ToString());
}
```

The 4 is the column index, but you could also use the string of the column name.